# Is ImagePicker plugin free to use?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I use these dependencies

```
  firebase_storage: ^6.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+21
  random_string: ^2.1.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.19.0+1
  firebase_core: ^0.6.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
  provider: ^4.3.2+3
  flutter_signin_button: ^1.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.15.0
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  image_cropper: 1.0.2
  camera : ^0.5.2+1
  path_provider: ^1.1.0
  path: ^1.6.2
  esys_flutter_share: ^1.0.2
```

Is `ImagePicker` for free to use in flutter application because when I use it in my app the message that it show *you should pay to use it or wait 10 second to take a photo*

Here is what I see when I open the camera in my app using my device
[image]

Comment: I am using image picker  but do not see any timer dialog

Comment: It's probably not the `image_picker` plugin as I'm using and I have never seen such an alert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ImagePicker is free to use. I use it before and I never get that popUp.